# biblatex-apa and \fullcite* --> year of ambiguous citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I writing my PhD thesis with LaTeX using biblatex-apa as bib style.

Besides the bibliography, a section will present a list of my publications during PhD. I do this using the `\fullcite` commands in a simple list environment.

I have some publications, where the authors and the year of publication are the same. Biblatex sets them like it would do in the bibliography:

- Author1, Author2, & Author3 (2011a). TitleA. JournalA, ...
- Author1, Author2, & Author3 (2011b). TitleB. JournalB, ...

I would like to omit the letters in the year statement (but only for the `\fullcite` items in my publications section, not generally, i.e. affecting the bibliography)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `\clearfield{extrayear}` to your `\fullcite` command. You can to that by redefining it, or by creating your own command.

This MWE redefines the existing `\fullcite`:

<sup>I have tried, without success, to patch the command (via [`xpatch`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xpatch)) instead of copying it and adding the `\clearfield{extrayear}`; perhaps this would be the best solution, but unfortunately, I couldn't do it.</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{a,
    author = {A. Uthor},
    title = {A title},
    year = {2013}
  }
  @book{b,
    author = {A. Uthor},
    title = {Another title},
    year = {2013}
  }

  @article{c,
    author = {A. Uthor},
    title = {Another title from the same year},
    journal = {Journal},
    date = {2013-09}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}%
      \global\let\blx@related@loop\@empty%
      \clearfield{extradate}% <---- added this
      }
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\autocites{a,b,c}

\fullcite{a}, \fullcite{b}, \fullcite{c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I've tried this and it does not work for me.  1) When I try the MWE, the fullcites have the appended year (2013a) and (2013b).  2) When I run it in my own file with my own bibliography cmpilation produces this error: "Boolean '\ifbbx:parens' undefined"

Comment: @SaMeji sorry for the long delay  The code for `fullcite` had been changed, so I just adapted it. Hope it helps!